# Deploying to heroku with heroku push command

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I installed heroku plugin called heroku-push. And I deployed my app with `heroku push --app appname`. I have settings.py and local_settings.py and in settings.py file `DEBUG is False` but in local_settings.py file `DEBUG is True`. And I included local_settings.py in .gitignore file. When I open my page in browser there is a message telling me `DEBUG=True`. Say that If local_settings.py also is deployed to server, there is a code in settings.py file
`try:
   from .local_settings import *
 except ImportError:
   pass`
What should I do? Heroku gives me `git@heroku.com:appname.git` But I can not view it or clone it. It gives me empty folder.

Comment: Try `heroku run bash --app appname` to see what files you have actually deployed.

Comment: If `local_settings.py` was previously committed, and only after added to `.gitignore`, it won't have any effect by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you create .gitignore file (if you didn't: `touch .gitignore`)
Now open .gitignore with your favorite text editor and paste in the following information about files Git should ignore:

```
### Django ###
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
__pycache__/
local_settings.py
```

I advise you to read this tutorial on medium it helped me to deploy my first django app :
https://medium.com/@BennettGarner/deploying-django-to-heroku-procfile-static-root-other-pitfalls-e7ab8b2ba33b

Comment: Hi Omar, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help It has the information you seem to have been missing while writing your post.